# Operation APPEND failed with HTTP500?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

```
package org.apache.spark.examples.kafkaToflink;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.RichSinkFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;

import com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLException;
import com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLFileOutputStream;
import com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLStoreClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.IfExists;
import com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.oauth2.AccessTokenProvider;
import com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider;

import scala.util.parsing.combinator.testing.Str;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.1.72:9092");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");
        DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(
                new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<String>("tenant", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties), "Kafka_Source");

        stream.addSink(new ADLSink()).name("Custom_Sink").setParallelism(128);
        env.execute("App");
    }
}

class ADLSink<String> extends RichSinkFunction<String> {

    private java.lang.String clientId = "***********";
    private java.lang.String authTokenEndpoint = "***************";
    private java.lang.String clientKey = "*****************";
    private java.lang.String accountFQDN = "****************";
    private java.lang.String filename = "/Bitfinex/ETHBTC/ORDERBOOK/ORDERBOOK.json";

    @Override
    public void invoke(String value) {

        AccessTokenProvider provider = new ClientCredsTokenProvider(authTokenEndpoint, clientId, clientKey);
        ADLStoreClient client = ADLStoreClient.createClient(accountFQDN, provider);
        try {
            client.setPermission(filename, "744");
            ADLFileOutputStream stream = client.getAppendStream(filename);

            System.out.println(value);
            stream.write(value.toString().getBytes());

            stream.close();

        } catch (ADLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.requestId);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
        }

    }

}
```

I am continuously trying to append a file which is in Azure data lake Store using while loop .But sometimes it gives this , Operation APPEND failed with HTTP500, error in starting or sometimes after 10 min. I am using java

Comment: Thanks for raising the question. HTTP 500 is a "server" error. I am asking the ADLS team to investigate and possibly reach out to you.

Comment: Can you provide information on whether you are (a) using append or concurrentappend (b) Whether this is happening in a single thread or multiple threads?

Comment: @AmitKulkarni I am using append and this is happening in single thread

Comment: @MichaelRys I just posted my code have a look .Small help will be a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anubhav, Azure Data Lake streams are single-writer streams - i.e., you cannot write to the same stream from multiple threads, unless you do some form of synchronization between these threads. This is because each write specifies the offset it is writing to, and with multiple threads, the offsets are not consistent.

You seem to be writing from multiple threads (`.setParallelism(128)` call in your code)

In your case, you have two choices:

1. Write to a different file in each thread. I do not know your use-case, but we have found that for a lot of cases that is the natural use of different threads - to write to different files.
2. If it is important to have all the threads write to the same file, then you will need to refactor the sink a little bit so that all the instances have reference to the same `ADLFileOutputStream`, and you will need to make sure the calls to `write()` and `close()` are synchronized.

Now, there is one more issue here - the error you got should have been an HTPP 4xx error (indicating a lease conflict, since the `ADLFileOutputStream`s acquire  lease), rather than HTTP 500, which says there was a server-side problem. To troubleshoot that, I will need to know your account name and time of access. That info is not safe to share on StackOverflow, so please open a support ticket for that and reference this SO question, so the issue gets eventually routed to me.